# a do-until loop in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, algorithm, loops

Is there a condition controlled loop in Swift 3.0 with a posttest that executes so long as the condition is false? If not, what would be the equivalent of a do-until loop in Swift 3.0? What is the performance benefits of the equivalents?

Comment: Why not just negate the condition in a `do-while`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the repeat-while loop:

```
repeat {
} while !condition
```

Comment: Is there a performance benefit that `repeat-while` has over `do-while` when their posttest conditions are negated? @Carcigenicate & @jhabbott

Comment: @Eric no... but do-while isn't a thing in Swift, `do` is for something else. Use repeat-while!

Comment: Thanks, @jhabbot! Why is there no do-until in Swift?

Comment: The language creators wanted to make it as easy to read and understand as possible. `do` something `until` doesn't express (in English) quite exactly what happens... whereas `repeat` something `while` does express that. Of course `while` and `until` mean the same thing but with a negated condition, so to make the language easier to learn and use less keywords, they decided it's better to use one or the other, and `while` probably fitted better with the most common conditions (`i <= 15`, `remaining > 0`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) on control flow.

From the document:

> The repeat-while loop in Swift is analogous to a do-while loop in
>   other languages.

Here’s the general form of a repeat-while loop:

```
repeat {

    statements

} while condition
```